# Debug/test specific activity declaration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-build

I'd like to test my `Fragment`. In order to do it I need to declare a test `Activity` which would contain the testing fragment.

As of 1.0 `AndroidStudio` release I'd like to know whether there's opportunity to declare an  `Activity` (for testing purposes) inside the debug build type or `androidTest` folder. At this point I have to add java file to the main `Sourceset` and corresponding record into main `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

7 years and no answer.

I do not know if it is possible to add it to androidTest, but you can add it to the src folder under a folder named debug/java/com/app_name/package_name, then, at the very least, it won't get added to the release